# Microsoft Graph API tests - get access on behalf of user

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I have the code that creates an extension for User with Graph API (.Net Core 3.1). And I have a test project for this code. But I need to authenticate as a user in order to create and use GraphServiceClient (the user has Global Administrator Role).

The goal is to have a working code that creates **schemaExtension** for **User**.

Now, to create an extension the client must have Delegated permission `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` which was granted to the registered App in the portal. But since this is a Delegated permission I need to authenticate as a user (in a test code). So my options are for authentication provider:

- Authorization code provider
- On-behalf-of provider
- Interactive provider

### For Authorization code provider:

```
            List<string> scopes = new List<string> { "Directory.AccessAsUser.All" };

            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(_appClientId.ToString())
                .WithRedirectUri(_redirectUri)
                .WithClientSecret(_appSecret) // or .WithCertificate(certificate)
                .Build();

            AuthorizationCodeProvider authProvider = new AuthorizationCodeProvider(confidentialClientApplication, scopes);
            _graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
```

I get an exception:

> Microsoft.Graph.Auth.AuthenticationException : Code: authenticationChallengeRequired

### For On-behalf-of provider:

```
            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(_appClientId.ToString())
                .WithRedirectUri(_redirectUri)
                .WithClientSecret(_appSecret)
                .Build();

            OnBehalfOfProvider authProvider = new OnBehalfOfProvider(confidentialClientApplication, scopes);

            _graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
```

I get

> NullReferenceException

on this line when I'm trying to actually create a schema:

```
SchemaExtension extension = await _graphServiceClient .SchemaExtensions.Request().AddAsync(schemaExtension);
```

### For Interactive provider:

```
IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .Build();

InteractiveAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new InteractiveAuthenticationProvider(publicClientApplication, scopes);
```

I get:

> Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException : Only loopback redirect uri is supported, but urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob was found. Configure http://localhost or http://localhost:port both during app registration and when you create the PublicClientApplication object.

And this last one I do not understand at all. So how can I make this delegated authentication work?

#### Addition

Here's the code that creates an extension but it doesn't depend on authorization:

```
  SchemaExtension schemaExtension = new SchemaExtension
  {
    Id = schemaName.Trim(),
    // Owner = _appClientId.ToString(),    
    Description = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(schemaDesc) ? string.Empty : schemaDesc.Trim(),
    TargetTypes = new List<string>
    {
      "User"
    },
    Properties = new List<ExtensionSchemaProperty>
    {
      new ExtensionSchemaProperty
      {
        Name = "isGlobalAdmin",
        Type = "Boolean"
      },
      new ExtensionSchemaProperty
      {
        Name = "isOrganizationAdmin",
        Type = "Boolean"
      }
    }
  };

  SchemaExtension extension = await GraphClient.SchemaExtensions.Request().AddAsync(schemaExtension); // GraphClient here === _graphServiceClient in the code above
```

Comment: Can you share the full code for the on behalf of flow? Including the initialisation of the schemaExtension object?

Comment: Added, please see the addition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my research, the different providers for Microsoft Graph use different protocols and are suitable for different environments. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=CS#InteractiveProvider)

## For Authorization code provider:

It uses [OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow). In normal, we use it for the situation that web app access web api. For more details, please refer to the [doucment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-overview)

## For Interactive provider

It uses [OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow). In normal, we use it for the  desktop apps(such as  WPF). Besides, please note that when we use the provider with MSAL.NET, [we must register "http://localhost" as a Public client (mobile & desktop) redirect URI for your AD application](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/msal-net-4#net-core-now-supports-interactive-authentication). For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-desktop-overview)

---

## update

If we want to use Interactive provider to call Microsoft graph, please refer to the following steps

1. Register Azure AD application
   [image]
2. Configure permissions
   [image]
3. Code

```
 static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {

            var clientId = "476944ed-e57c-4b2c-b18d-93b5dd5f1bca";
            string[] scopes = { "Directory.AccessAsUser.All" };
            #please provide the redirect url http://localhost when you create the client
            IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost") 
            .Build();

            InteractiveAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new InteractiveAuthenticationProvider(publicClientApplication, scopes);

            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
            var schemaExtension = new SchemaExtension
            {
                Id = "courses",
                Description = "Graph Learn training courses extensions",
                TargetTypes = new List<string>()
                    {
                        "Group"
                    },
                Properties = new List<ExtensionSchemaProperty>()
                    {
                        new ExtensionSchemaProperty
                        {
                            Name = "courseId",
                            Type = "Integer"
                        },
                        new ExtensionSchemaProperty
                        {
                            Name = "courseName",
                            Type = "String"
                        },
                        new ExtensionSchemaProperty
                        {
                            Name = "courseType",
                            Type = "String"
                        }
                    }
            };

            var result = await graphClient.SchemaExtensions.Request().AddAsync(schemaExtension);
            foreach (var type in result.TargetTypes) {
                Console.WriteLine(type);

            }
```

[image]

Comment: All these docs I already know by heart. How does this help my case?

Comment: @alvipeo I have updated my answer. Please check it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Trying right now. if this works, I'll have a drink! :)

Comment: ok, not yet. I tried this code as a Test method and it opened the browser (!) for user authentication. I authenticated successfully and it redirected me to `http://localhost:63371/?code=OA...`. At this point the test finished with exception - `Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException : Code: Service_InternalServerError`.

Is there any way to simulate this authentication in a test? Or just create a test from this?

Comment: @alvipeo According to your error,  you have completed AD auth and sent your request to graph server but the graph server cannot process your request. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/errors). Could you please tell me what you want to do?

Comment: The code that creates a schema extension for User is in Test method (xUnit). So I run that test. Now I think I should make a real web project and see if it works. And then I'll just do E2E testing probably. Otherwise, I don't see how to make this code run in a test.

Comment: The web app (.Net Core 3.1 Razor Pages) doesn't work too. Is there any ASP.NET Core 3.1 WORKING examples for Graph API? Do you know? I only see with Device code flow :/

Comment: @alvipeo If you want to call graph API in .net core web app, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/dotnet-core.

Comment: ok, thank you! I found the sample buried deep in the docs for the web app. It really seems like MS doesn't want developers to be able to work with Graph API. It's EXTREMELY complicated even for seasoned developers.

Comment: The different authentication providers (at least some of them) are basically different OAuth 2.0 authentication flows. Microsoft designed their API to make it (relatively) easy to use it without in-depth knowledge of OAuth 2.0. I cannot tell if they succeeded, but if they didn't, then I would recommend reading up on OAuth. It may be helpful. For example, you may start here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2

Comment: _It uses OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow. In normal, we use it for the desktop apps_

This sounds like a bad idea, since authorization code flow requires a confidential client (which can hold a client secret without exposing it). A desktop app cannot be a confidential client.